# How to show that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $x=1$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

How to show that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $x=1$?

Comment: What definition of "continuous" are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you know that the product of ciontinuous functions is continuous?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To prove the limit exists using the fundamental definition. Here is how you proceed.

We must show that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $\delta >0$ such that
if $0<|x-1|<\delta\,,$ then $|x^2-1|<\epsilon$. 
Finding $\delta$ is most easily accomplished by working backward. Manipulate the second inequality until it contains a term of the form $x-1$ as in the first inequality. This is easy here. First
$$ |x^2-1|=|x+1||x-1| \,. $$
In the above, there is unwanted factor of $|x+1|$, that must be bounded. If we make certain that $\delta<1$
$$ |x-1|<\delta<1 \,,$$
then 
$$ |x-1|< \delta \implies |x-1|< 1 \implies -1<x-1<1 \,$$
Adding $2$ to the last inequality gives
$$ 1<x+1<3 \implies |x+1|<3\,.$$ 
So, if
$$ |x^2-1|=|x+1||x-1|<3|x-1|<\epsilon \implies |x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\,. $$
Now, select $\delta = \mathrm{min}\left\{ 1, \frac{\epsilon}{3}\right\} $.

Check: given $\epsilon >0$, let  $\delta = \mathrm{min}\left\{ 1, \frac{\epsilon}{3}\right\} $. Then $0<|x-1|<\delta$ implies that

$$ |x^2-1|=|x+1||x-1|<3|x-1|<3 \delta\le 3 \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon.$$

Comment: Do you know a book, where I can find more exercises with solutions like yours? Thanks!

Comment: It says, "select $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$". What if $\delta =1$?

Comment: @AlJebr If $\delta = 1$ then by the definition of $\min$, we have 1<$\epsilon $/3, and thus $ 3 < \epsilon $. Thus following the last line in the post, we have $|x^2-1|<3|x-1| < 3 \delta = 3 < \epsilon $

Comment: @AlJebr If you're curious why we need the $\delta = \min \{1,\epsilon /3 \}$ in the first place, let me explain the logic. The OP showed that if $|x-1| <1 $ and $ |x-1| < \epsilon/3 $ then $|x^2 -1|< \epsilon $.  Note that choosing $\delta$
  to be the smallest of these two bounds $\{1,\epsilon /3 \}$ implies the other. Ie, WLOG, if $a<b$
  and $|x-x_{0}|<a$
 , then $|x-x_{0}|<a<b$
 , and so by the transitive property, $|x-x_{0}|<b$
  holds as well.

Comment: @EvanRosica Then is the choice of taking $\delta$ < 1 arbitrary? Could we have chosen another condition such as $\delta$ < 2 or $\delta$ < 0.5? Also, we are able to impose the restriction that $\delta$ < 1 because the value of $\delta$ can be arbitrarily small right?

Comment: @TanYongBoon Good question. My analysis is a bit rusty these days, but it looks like this argument will work for any $\delta = \min \{\alpha, \frac{\epsilon}{\alpha+2}\}$. E.g. Letting $\delta = \min\{2,\frac{\epsilon}{4}\}$ should work.

Comment: I see, thanks! @EvanRosica

Answer (score 17):

If you want to know if a function is continuous, then the *definition* of what it takes for a function to be continuous is important.  From Calculus by Varberg, Purcell, and Rigdon:

> Let $f$ be defined on an open interval containing $c$.  We say that
>   $f$ is **continuous** at $c$ if $$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c).$$

Notice, this actually contains three parts,

1. $f(c)$ is defined
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists
3. The two values in parts 1 and 2 are equal.

So, you need to show the 3 parts of this are true with the function $f(x) = x^2$ and when $c = 1$, or figure out which part is not true.

Is $f(1)$ defined?  What is it?  Does $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} x^2$ exist?  What is its value?  Are the two values the same?

Answer (score 7):

The product of continuous functions is continuous. The function $x$ is continuous, hence also $x^2=x\cdot x$ is continuous.

The proof that the product of continuos functions is continuous, simply relies on the theorem that states the limit of the product is the product of the limits.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Choose $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon+1}-1 > 0$. Assume that 
$|x-1|<\delta$. Now
$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x^2-1|=|(x-1)(x+1)|\leq |x-1||x+1|<(\sqrt{\epsilon+1}-1)(\sqrt{\epsilon+1}-1+2)=\epsilon$

, because if $|x-1|<\delta \Leftrightarrow -\delta < x-1 < \delta|+2 \Leftrightarrow -\delta+2 < x-1+2 < \delta+2 \Leftrightarrow |x+1| < \delta+2 =\sqrt{\epsilon+1}-1+2$

then $|x+1|<\sqrt{\epsilon+1}-1+2$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 3):

In his 1821 text "Cours d'Analyse", Cauchy defined continuity of $y=f(x)$ by requiring that an infinitesimal $x$-increment should necessarily produce an infinitesimal change in $y$.  According to this definition, if $f(x)=x^2$, then for $\alpha$ infinitesimal, the change in $y$ is precisely $f(x+\alpha)-f(x)=(x+\alpha)^2-x^2=(x+\alpha+x)(x+\alpha-x)=\alpha(2x+\alpha)$.  Since $2x+\alpha$ is finite, the product $\alpha(2x+\alpha)$ is infinitesimal. Therefore $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous by definition.