# Showing a function is continuous from the definition

Tags: analysis

I am trying to recall this from memory from an exam that I have lost.  I'm wondering if this approach is correct - I most likely fumbled this up during the exam.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=3|x|+5$.  Show this is continuous.

Let $\epsilon > 0$  Fix $x_0$.  Then for $|x-x_0|< \delta$.

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|3|x|-5-3|x_0|+5|=3||x|-|x_0|| \leq 3|x-x_0|<3\delta$

If $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ we get what we desired.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: Does it matter that the function goes from $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: First, see functions with two variables and see what happens. Continuity in higher dimensions is harder to handle than in one dimension.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Is my answer completely wrong?  I'm trying to make sure I understand how to apply the definition of continuity properly.

Comment: This question is a good example where continuity in higher dimension is *exactly as easy to handle* as in dimension 1 (for every norm). If you replace $|x|$, $|x_0|$ and $|x-x_0|$ by $\|x\|$, $\|x_0\|$ and $\|x-x_0\|$, and if you use the triangular inequality for the norm $\|\ \|$ like you did for $|\ |$, then your proof will be perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured he did the $\mathbb{R}^n$ to toy with your minds a bit.

Comment: Your current answer is absolutely correct, but since you are not sure about it, you should tell us at which step you have doubts.