# Confusing calculus question

Tags: calculus

I am unsure how to solve the following

Using the graph $f(x)=x^2/3$ find the largest possible $\delta$ such that if

$$0< |x-3|< \delta$$ 
then 
$$0< \left|\frac{x^2}{3}-3\right|<1.$$

I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Such that if what?

Comment: *Such that if* what?

Comment: Surely there is more to the question.  What is the rest of the sentence at line 2?

Comment: I think there is something missing in your question.

Comment: @GitGud, you were 5 seconds faster than me... lol

Comment: Lynch the infidel!

Comment: I dont know why but what I wrote did not show up..

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 1):

First, you can ignore the $0 \lt $ part as unless $x=3$ the contents of the absolute value sign will be non-zero, so just concentrate on keeping it less than $1$.  For the absolute value to be exactly $1$, you must have $\frac {x^2}3=2$ or $\frac {x^2}3=4$.  So solve both of those and take the smaller difference from $3$ as $\delta$

Comment: I solved both of them and got square root(6) and square root(12) does this mean I subtract square root 12 - square root(6) and the subtract this from 3 to get delta.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez:  you are right that you need $x \in (\sqrt 6,\sqrt{12})$ for $|\frac {x^2}3-3|\lt 1$.  But that interval is not symmetric around $3$, while having $|x-3| \lt \delta$ produces a symmetric interval.  So you need to choose the "worst case" direction.  That is why I said to take the smaller difference from $3$.