# Limit Using Definition

Tags: real-analysis

How do I evaluate this limit using the definition?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2x+3}{x-4}$$

I know it equals 2, but the delta-epsilon argument trips me up here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
f(x) = \frac{2x+3}{x-4} = 2 + \frac{11}{x-4}.
$$
That much follows from long division: the quotient is $2$ and the remainder is $11$.  You want $f(x)$ to differ from $2$ by less than $\varepsilon>0$ when $x$ is big enough.  The question is how big is big enough.  The difference between $f(x)$ and $2$ is the second term above, $11/(x-4)$.  Since $x-4$ is positive, you can say $11/(x-4)<\varepsilon$ if $x>\frac{11}{\varepsilon}+4$.

Comment: so does this $\frac{11}{\epsilon} + 4$ become my $d$?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by $d$.  If you're tyring to prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $d$ such that $|f(x)-2|<\varepsilon$ whenever $x>d$, then you can use $d=\frac{11}{\varepsilon}+4$.

Comment: that is indeed what I mean, sorry. used the notion I was given in class without being clear! thanks again.