# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x} = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, radicals, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to teach myself how to do $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs and would like to know if I solved this proof correctly. The answer given (Spivak, but in the solutions book) was very different.

---

**Exercise:** Prove $\lim_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x} = 1$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$.

**My Proof:**

We have that $0 < |x-1| < \delta $.

Also, $|x - 1| = \bigl|(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)\bigr| = |\sqrt{x}-1||\sqrt{x}+1| < \delta$.

$\therefore |\sqrt{x}-1|< \frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{x}+1|}$

Now we let $\delta = 1$. Then
\begin{array}{l}
-1<x-1<1 \\
\therefore  0 < x < 2 \\
\therefore  1 < \sqrt{x} + 1<\sqrt{2} + 1 \\
\therefore  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 1}<1.
\end{array}

We had that $$|\sqrt{x}-1|< \frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{x}+1|} \therefore |\sqrt{x}-1|<\delta$$

By letting $\delta=\min(1, \epsilon)$, we get that $|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon$ if $0 < |x-1| < \delta $.

Thus, $\lim_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x} = 1$.

---

Is my proof correct? Is there a better way to do it (still using $\epsilon-\delta$)?

Comment: Looks good to me. Although perhaps unnecessary because it's easy to argue that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1} \le 1$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I see. In that case, do I still need to let $\delta=min(1, \epsilon)$ or can it simply be $\delta=\epsilon$? Thank you.

Comment: You can simply let $\varepsilon = \delta$.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks!

Comment: @CameronWilliams if we did $\varepsilon=\delta$ would the proof be as follows? We have $|\sqrt{x}-1|\lt \frac\delta{|\sqrt{x}+1|}$. Let $\varepsilon=\delta$, then $|\sqrt{x}-1|\lt \frac\varepsilon{|\sqrt{x}+1|} \leq \varepsilon$ since $\sqrt{x}\geq0 \implies \sqrt{x}+1\geq1 \implies \frac{\varepsilon}{|\sqrt{x}+1|}\leq\varepsilon$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is correct but can be simplified. You don't need the part "Now let $\delta=1$...". In fact it is always true that
$$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt x + 1} \le 1
$$
since $\sqrt x \ge 0$.

Also, a matter of style. In the first line you don't *have* $0 < |x-1|<\delta$ but you *suppose* it (this is because $\delta$ is not already been given, but has to be found yet). The same when you write "let $\delta = 1$" you should write "if $\delta \le 1$ ..."

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Wrong. You need to let $\delta\le 1$ because if $\delta>1$, then $\sqrt{x}$ may not be a real number.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is correct.
We can also adopt the following:
Since $|\sqrt x-1|\lt \epsilon$ is equivalent with $1-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2\lt x\lt 1+2\epsilon+\epsilon^2$, we can choose $\delta$ so that $0\lt\delta\lt \min\{|-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2|,|2\epsilon+\epsilon^2|\}$.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The backward approach. :D

Comment: That's an interesting approach! Thanks.

Comment: @awllower How  $0\lt\delta\lt \min\{|-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2|,|2\epsilon+\epsilon^2|\}$ proves that $|x-1|<\delta$? Please elaborate this step.

Comment: Our aim here is that for every $|x-1|\lt\delta$, we have $|\sqrt x-1|\lt\varepsilon$. Now if $0\lt\delta\lt \min\{|-2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2|,|2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2|\}$, then for $|x-1|\lt\delta$, we deduce $1-\delta\lt x\lt1+\delta$, from which the conclusion follows. Note also that when $\varepsilon$ is small, $\varepsilon^2-2\varepsilon$ is negative.

Comment: You need to let $\epsilon\le 1$ to square/raise to the even positive power $2$ the inequality. E.g., $-4<3$, but $(-4)^2\not < 3^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Using your work here is another flavor of this proof:

Let $\epsilon >0$, and put 
 $\delta= \epsilon(\sqrt{x}+1)$.

Assume $0<|x−1|<\delta$.

Then
     $$|F(x)−L|=|x−1|
             =∣(\sqrt{x}−1)(\sqrt{x}+1)∣.$$
By our assumption that  $0<|x−1|<\delta$, we have
    $$|F(x) - L| <|1/(\sqrt{x}+1)|\delta = (1/(\sqrt{x}+1))ϵ(\sqrt{x}+1))  = \epsilon.$$

By letting $\delta=\epsilon(\sqrt{x}+1)$,  we get that $|x−1|<\epsilon$ if 0<|x−1|<δ.
Thus, $\lim_{x\to 1} F(x) = L$

The scratch work is usually omitted as far as finding the co-efficient of delta itself. Then just find the co-eff inverse and include epsilon and it falls out at the end. There is a good link on math exchange that shows a template of how to structure delta-epsilon proofs. It is how I learned to write them up, and this is that method. Good luck.

P.S. * represents multiplication, and the square roots were not working. I am unfamiliar with LaTex so this is the best I can do.

Comment: You might want to review: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1