# Show $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at x=4

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I just really need to make sure that I am understanding the process for doing these.

Scratch work: We have $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{4}| = |\sqrt{x}-2|= |\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x+2}}|= \frac{|x-4|}{|\sqrt{x}+2|}$. Here we suppose, $|x-4|<\delta<1 \Rightarrow \frac{|x-4|}{|\sqrt{x}+2|}<\frac{\delta}{2}.$ So we're done if we take, $\delta$=$min${$1,2\epsilon$}? In the previous steps I multiplied by the conjugate.

Comment: A related [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error crept in: $\sqrt x+2<5$ would make $\frac1{\sqrt x+2}>\frac15$ instead of $<\frac15$.
However, we have $\frac 1{\sqrt x+2}\le \frac12$ right away without ado.
So you can take $\delta=\min\{2\epsilon,4\}$.
(You need to bound $\delta$ merely to have $x\ge0$ and $\sqrt x$ defined, but this is not strictly required)

Comment: Where did the 4 come from sorry?

Comment: @Crypto More generally, to show continuity of $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ at $x_0>0$, you can pick $\delta=\min\{\sqrt{x_0}\epsilon, x_0\}$. We shold ensure $\delta<x_0$ so that $\sqrt x$ is defined in the first place. Then again, the definition of continuity asks only for $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$ for which $f(x)$ is *defined* - so this restriction is not really needed, you can take $\delta=\sqrt{x_0}\epsilon$.