# $\vert(1/\sqrt{x}-3) +1\vert$ Having trouble getting this to $\vert x-4\vert$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-3}=-1|$$

I need to somehow move from the above function and arrive at $| x - 4 |$

This is part of a limits problem (an introductory one), but it's the algebra that's stumping me... I've checked out the problem and it's correct, so there must be a way and I am totally missing it. Please help!

(also, please forgive my English, I may not be using the proper math terminology)

To clarify:

I have a limit:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-3}=-1
$$
and I am asked to prove this is correct by following this:
$$
0 < |x-4| < \delta \rightarrow |\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-3} - (-1) | < \epsilon
$$

As explained in class, I am supposed to take the function that has the square root involved and find a way to make it match with what's on the left of the arrow.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "move from the above function and arrive at." These are two rather different functions.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean, let me clarify up on the question, it will allow me more space

Comment: formatting error! the x->4 is supposed to be under Lim

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are I think looking at 
$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-3}+1\right|.$$
Bring this to a common denominator.
We get
$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{\sqrt{x}-3}\right|.$$
Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{x}+2$. We get
$$\frac{|x-4|}{|\sqrt{x}-3|(\sqrt{x}+2)}.$$

**Remark:** We started with absolute value signs around the expression, since you put some stress on wanting that. But it is at least more pleasant to type if we do the algebra on without absolute values, and take absolute values at the end.

**Added:** Presumably the purpose of the transformation is to prove that the limit of our expression as $x\to 4$ is $0$. So suppose we are given an $\epsilon \gt 0$. We want to find a $\delta$ such that if $|x-4|\lt \delta$ then our expression has absolute value less than $\epsilon.

As a first step, we make sure that $\delta \lt 1/2$. The purpose of this is to make sure $|\sqrt{x}-3|$ is not too small. That puts $x$ between $3.5$ and $4.5$, making $\sqrt{x}\lt \sqrt{4.5}\approx 2.12132\lt 2.2$. It follows that $|\sqrt{x}-3|\gt 0.8$.

The $\sqrt{x}+2$ part in the denominator is $\gt 2$. So if $\delta\lt 1/2$, the absolute value of the denominator is greater than $1.6$. (We could do better, but don't need to bother. Worse is fine too, as long as we get some bound.)

It follows that as long as we ensure that $\delta\lt \frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-3}+1\right|\lt \frac{|x-4|}{1.6}.$$
To make this less than $\epsilon$, we take $\delta=(1.6)\epsilon$. Not quite! We make $\delta=\min(1/2,(1.6)\epsilon)$, because our inequality was obtained under the assumption that $\delta\lt 1/2$.

Comment: Right with you up till now, but We still haven't arrived at just the | x-4 |, with no denominator. I will keep researching!

Comment: We will never arrive at an equivalent expression that just involves $|x-4|$. When you are going through your proof that the limit is $0$, we will make **estimates** for the entries in the denominator when $x$ is within $\delta$ of $4$. The details are straightforward, and could be added to the post, but you did not ask about the proof that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Although, just to check if I'm way off base  here, could I do something like this? $ \frac{x-4}{x-\sqrt{x}-6}= 0 $, then from that (by moving the denominator over to the right) later obtain $ x-4 $ ?

Comment: No. I will add a remark at the end of the post, making a brief description of how to get the limit result. About $10$ minutes.