# Give an $ε$-$δ$ proof to show that $\lim_{x\to1}(3x − 2) = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

Give an $ε$-$δ$ proof to show that $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to1}(3x − 2) = 1$$

please help me with this question.

Comment: See here for the [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $$0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |(3x-2)-1|<\varepsilon.$$
We start by playing around with the second inequality. A little algebra yields:
$$|(3x-2)-1|=|3x-3|=|3(x-1)|=|3|\cdot|x-1|<\varepsilon$$$$|x-1|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$

So in other words, another way of writing $|(3x-2)-1| < \varepsilon$ is $|x-1| < \varepsilon / 3$. Now we are reading to write our proof. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, if we require that $|x-1|<\varepsilon/3$, then it follows that $|3x-3|<\varepsilon$, and therefore $|(3x-2) - 1| < \varepsilon$. Therefore, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ that satisfies the inequalities the limit definition requires, so we can say that $$\lim_{x \to 1}(3x-2)=1$$

Comment: why does delta equal |x-1|?

Comment: $\delta$ does not equal $|x-1|$, $\delta = \varepsilon/3$

Answer (score 3):

You have $|(3x-2)-1| = 3 |x-1|$. So, if $|x-1| < \delta$, then $|(3x-2)-1| < 3 \delta$.

So, if you want $|(3x-2)-1| < \epsilon$, then choose $\delta = \frac{1}{3}\epsilon$.

Comment: why does delta equal epsilon/3?

Comment: If you choose $\delta$ to have that value, then the difference between $3x-2$ and $1$ will be less than $\epsilon$. You can choose $\delta = \frac{1}{5} \epsilon$ if you want. You just need to find any $\delta>0$ so that the $\epsilon$ bound holds.