# $f$ is continuous in $x$ using epsilon-delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Show if $f$ is continuous in $x \iff$ for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta >0$ such that for all $\zeta \in (a,b): |f(\zeta) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, whenever $|\zeta - x| < \delta$.

---

I know if $f$ is continuous in $x$, then $\lim_{\zeta\to x} f(\zeta) = f(x)$.

But how can I use that to show equivalence for both statements?

Comment: What does $\lim_{\zeta\to x}f(\zeta)=f(x)$ mean?

Comment: sry did forget sth.....

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Peraphs the user thought a generalization of a continuous function writing $x$ like a fixed point.

Comment: @ArminZierlinger Please write the definition of a limit in the same way that you wrote the definition of continuity

Comment: @Sebastiano Excuse me, what?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I have thought that the function is $y=f(\zeta)$ and $f(x)$ it is the computation of $f(\zeta)$ in $x$.

Comment: Related duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494767/show-continuity-using-epsilon-delta-definition or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600788/epsilon-delta-definition-to-prove-that-f-is-a-continuous-function

Comment: Hint: Can you write exactly the definition of convergence, i.e. the signification of $\lim_{\zeta\to x} f(\zeta) = f(x)$ ?