# Proving that a function satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^{3}-y^{3}|$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $[a,b]$ such that $0<a<b$:

$\forall x,y\in[a,b],x\neq y,|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^{3}-y^{3}|$ where $k>0$ .

Prove that the function $f$ is continuous.

**My attempt**

I let $\epsilon>0$ and I let $\eta=\frac{\epsilon}{k}$ so by definition of uniform continuity:

$|x^{3}-y^{3}|<\eta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^{3}-y^{3}|<k\eta=\epsilon$

So therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous. Can anyone check my work please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492) for a related problem.

Comment: Yea but in my cause I have to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous no just continuous at a certain point. I also believe this is a Lipschitz function.

Comment: When you factor $|x^3-y^3|$, you left with a factor you need to bound, which can be done by noting that $x,y \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes thank you very much for your help take a look at my comment to your answer. I believe that's what I have to do right?

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You've to choose $\eta$ such that $|x-y|<\eta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$ You've shown it for $|x^3-y^3|<\eta.$ I would rather prefer:

Since $x,y\ge a$

$$|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^{3}-y^{3}|=k|x^2+xy+y^2||x-y|\le 4a^2k|x-y|$$

and hence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Alright thank you very much so all I have to chose is $\eta=\frac{\epsilon}{4a^{2}k}$ so I get $4a^{2}k|x-y|<4a^{2}k(\eta)=\epsilon$

Comment: Yep...$$$$$$$$$$