# Prove $mx+b$ is continuous at any point in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-verification

I need to prove, $mx+b$ is continuous at any point in $\mathbb{R}$

Now, as I have thought of there's 2 possible cases: 
1) $m = 0$ 
2) $m \neq 0$

So for case #2, $m < 0 \vee m > 0$ , 
and we can assume without loss of generality $m>0$

$|x-a| < \delta \longrightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon  $ 
$|x-a| < \delta \longrightarrow | (mx+b) - (ma+b) | < \epsilon$ 
$|x-a| < \delta \longrightarrow |mx-ma| < \epsilon $ 
$|x-a| < \delta \longrightarrow |x-a| < \epsilon/m $

And then, let $\delta =\epsilon/m  $ 
$|x-a| < \delta \longrightarrow |x-a| <\epsilon/m $ 
$\longrightarrow |mx -ma| < \epsilon$ 
 
$\longrightarrow |mx +b -ma -b|\epsilon$ 
$\longrightarrow |f(x) - f(a)|\epsilon$ 
Thus $mx+b $ is continuous when $m > 0 \vee m<0$

But, now how do I prove it when $m = 0$?

I end up with $\epsilon/m$ and $m = 0$ and that is no correct.

So, how should I prove $mx+b$ is continuous when $m = 0$ OR am I approaching the problem wrong?

Thanks in advance for all the help! :D

Comment: You can save yourself some trouble by consolidating some cases :)

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon >0$.  Choose $\delta=\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{|m|}$.  Now let $|x-a|<\delta$.  We have,

\begin{align*}
|(mx+b)-(ma+b)|&=|m||x-a|<|m|\delta=\epsilon\\
\end{align*}

Therefore, $f(x)=mx+b$ is continuous at $a$.  $a$ was arbitrary so continuity holds everywhere.

Comment: Also if $m=0$ then let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta$ can be any value you want.  No matter what value you pick, the difference in function values will be zero.  Pick $\delta=10000$ if you want.