# Delta Epsilon Proof Help!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to a} x^4 = a^4 $$

for $a$ an arbitrary value so is it alright when I am into the proof  allowing me to find what each is strictly less than! and then allowing me to write that delta is equivalent to 
$$\min\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{2},1\right)$$

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: YesThats the technique Im actually using

Comment: Am I right any one!!

Comment: It would be useful to see more work and then we could more easily check if you got it right and, if you're not right, we could more easily see where to help you. :)

Comment: The choice is more complicated than $\min(\varepsilon/2,1).$ In particular the choice should have $a$ in it, also one might have to treat $a=0$ separately from $a \neq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

First if $a=0$ one only needs that $|x|<\delta$ implies $|x^4|<\varepsilon$ achieved by $\delta=\varepsilon^{\frac14}.$

Now suppose $a>0$ and assume that $\delta<1$ (which will be put with another inequality to get the final $\delta$). If we factor $|x^4-a^4|$ we have one factor as $|x-a|$ and the other is 
$$|x^3+x^2a+xa^2+a^3|,\tag{1}$$
which needs bounding. From $|x-a|<1$ we have $a-1<x<a+1$ and since in this case $a>0$ we know $|x|<a+1.$ Now using the triangle inequality on $(1)$ and properties of absolute value, we get that the factor in $(1)$ is bounded above by $4\cdot (a+1)^3.$ [Here have also used $a<a+1$.]

So if we now choose 
$$\delta = \min [ 1, \frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot (a+1)^3}],$$
we can show from the above by tracing the steps backward that from $|x-a|<\delta$ it follows that $|x^4-a^4|<\varepsilon.$

There is also the case $a<0$ to treat, for which the inequality $a-1<x<a+1$ from above leads to the different looking upper bound $|a-1|$ for $|x|$, but otherwise this case should run similarly.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to showing that $f(x) = x^4$ is continuous at the point $a$.  It is easy to show that $g(x) = x$ is continuous, just let $\delta = \epsilon$.  Now just use the fact (or prove it for yourself) that a product of continuous functions is continuous and use induction.

Comment: It seems more like OP is going for a specific proof for $f(x)=x^4$ via epsilon/delta methods, rather than by applying general theorems.