# Using the epsilon-delta to prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^2}{x+2} = \frac{1}{3} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to use the epsilon-delta definition to prove 
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^2}{x+2} = \frac{1}{3} $.
Could someone please check if i got this right?

$ \forall  \epsilon >0, \exists  \delta >0$ s.t. if $0< | x-1 | < \delta$ , then  $|  \frac{x^2}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3}  | < \epsilon $.

$|  \frac{3x^2 - x - 2}{3(x+2)} | =  |  \frac{(3x+2)(x-1)}{3x+6}|< \epsilon $

Let $\delta=\frac{1}{3}$. Then, $|x-1|<\frac{1}{3} \Rightarrow |x|<\frac{4}{3}, |3x+2|<6$..

Then, $|  \frac{(3x+2)(x-1)}{3x+6}|<|  \frac{6(x-1)}{6}|<\epsilon $

$|  x-1|<\epsilon $, so  $\delta$ =min{1/3,  $\epsilon$ }

i think this feels correct, but to be sure... i thank in advance!

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, but that alone does not make a correct solution. It should be clear what the connection between the different lines is. The first line is what you want to prove, so say that.

> We have to show: $ \forall  \epsilon >0, \exists  \delta >0$ s.t. if $0< | x-1 | < \delta$ , then  $|  \frac{x^2}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3}  | < \epsilon $.

I personally would have used more English words (“We have to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta$ such that...”), but that is a matter of taste.

If I was grading this as homework, then regarding your next line I would ask: Where does the $\epsilon$ come from? So far you have not introduced an epsilon. Of course, I understand that you *want* that inequality to hold, but then you have to say that. I would prefer to just state what you are actually doing, namely a quick calculation:

> We have $|  \frac{x^2}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3}  | = |  \frac{3x^2 - x - 2}{3(x+2)} | =  |  \frac{(3x+2)(x-1)}{3x+6}|$.

You begin the next line with “let $\delta=\frac13$”. This is not good, because actually you want to make a statement that holds whenever $\delta\le\frac13$. But so far there is no need to introduce $\delta$, just state what you are claiming.

> We note that for $|x-1|<\frac{1}{3}$ we have $0<|x|<\frac{4}{3}$ and hence $|3x+2|<6$ and $|  \frac{(3x+2)(x-1)}{3x+6}|<|  \frac{6(x-1)}{6}|=\lvert x-1\rvert$.

I have added $0<\lvert x\rvert$, because you are using this for $\lvert 3x+6\rvert>6$.

Now we can wrap things up. What I do not like about your formulation is the “so  $\delta =\mathrm{min}\{1/3,  \epsilon \}$”. Since $\delta$ has not yet been defined, you cannot claim that it equals something else. What you mean is that *setting* $\delta$ to this value will work. So let's just do this.

> Now let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We set $\delta =\mathrm{min}\{1/3,  \epsilon \}$. Then for all $x$ with $\lvert x-1\rvert<\delta$ we have 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left\lvert\frac{x^2}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3}\right\rvert
> &<\lvert x-1\rvert&&\text{because $|x-1|<\frac{1}{3}$}
> \\&<\delta\le\epsilon.
> \end{align*}
>   This is what we had to show.

Now I am sure that you can still improve some of these formulations. The important thing is that you really ask yourself what your claims are and that you express these clearly.

Comment: Thank you! this helps me to understand the whole epsilon-delta proofs much more.

Answer (score -2):

There is a slight mistake you made 3x+2 < 6 and 3x+6<6

All in all this is a correct proof except that slight mistake.

But if I were you I would use some theorems about limits to handle this much more easier.Here is how I would have done that.

It is true that if $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l$$ $$and$$ $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = m$$ then following are also true $$\lim_{x \to a } f(x)g(x) = lm$$ and $$\lim_{x \to a}(f+g)(x) = l + m $$

Using these facts we can then transform your limit into something like this $$\frac{\lim_{x \to 1} x^2}{\lim_{x \to 1} x + \lim_{x \to 1}2}$$

Since 2 would be constant function its limit will be 2.
Since x approaches 1 near one so does sqaure of x

Thus we can conclude that:$$\frac{\lim_{x \to 1} x^2}{\lim_{x \to 1} x + \lim_{x \to 1}2} = \frac{1}{1+2}=\frac13$$

Comment: I do not think that this is what he was asked to do.

Comment: This is what he is specifically not asking for.

Comment: I answered his question and gave mine alternative.I said his proof is correct,but he has a slight overlook.

Comment: An even shorter proof is: This is a rational function which is defined for $x=1$, and rational functions are continuous.