# How to complete this epsilon delta proof

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

Prove $\lim_{x\to 1} {2+4x \over 3} = 2$ using the epsilon delta definition of a limit.

if $0 < \left|x-1\right| < \delta$ then $\left|{2+4x \over 3}-2\right| < \epsilon$

scratch work for finding $\delta$
$$
\left|{2+4x \over 3}-2\right| < \epsilon
$$
$$
2-\epsilon < {2+4x \over 3} < 2 + \epsilon
$$
$$
6-3\epsilon < 2+4x < 6 + 3\epsilon
$$

$$
4-3\epsilon < 4x < 4 + 3\epsilon
$$

$$
1-\frac34\epsilon < x < 1 + \frac34\epsilon
$$

$$
\frac34\epsilon < x-1 < \frac34\epsilon
$$

$$
\left|x-1\right| < \frac34\epsilon
$$
This is where I need help.

Given $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta = \frac34\epsilon$

$$\left|{2+4x\over 3}-2\right| < \frac43\delta$$
$$-\frac43\delta < {2+4x \over 3}-2 < \frac43\delta $$
$$2-\frac43\delta < {2+4x\over 3}< 2 + \frac43\delta$$
$$6-4\delta<2+4x < 6+4\delta $$
$$4-4\delta<4x<4+4\delta$$
$$1-\delta<x<1+\delta$$
$$\left|x-1\right|<\delta$$

I'm pretty sure the $\frac43\delta$ part is wrong on the first line which makes the rest wrong but I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You want to show $0 < |x-1| < \delta$ implies $|\frac{2+4x}{3} - 2| < \epsilon$.  Which means you should start from $0 < |x-1| < \frac{3}{4} \epsilon$ and argue from there.

Comment: I have wondered about that myself, but tons of textbook examples show arguing from the 2nd equation. Including the 2 I have with me.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first part of your solution is correct.  You have indeed found a $\delta=\frac34\epsilon$ that will work.  Then you proceed like this.
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0\ \text{such that }|x-1|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{2+4x}{3}-2\right|<\epsilon$$
Let $\delta=\frac34\epsilon$.  Then,
$$|x-1|<\delta\implies|x-1|<\frac34\epsilon\implies\frac43|x-1|<\epsilon\implies\left|\frac{4x-4}{3}\right|<\epsilon\quad\implies\left|\frac{2+4x-6}{3}\right|<\epsilon\implies\left|\frac{2+4x}{3}-2\right|<\epsilon\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
And we are done.

Comment: You stated the first part of my solution is correct, and I was pretty sure it was already. What I am confused on though is how my second part is correct as stated by Lord Soth. How can I pick a constant such as $\frac43$ for the purpose of canceling out the $\frac34$ for the $\epsilon$?

Comment: What do you mean pick a constant such as $\frac43.$  You already found a constant $\delta=\frac34\epsilon.$  Now, the $\frac34$ cancelled out from the $\epsilon$ by multiplying each side of the inequality by the reciprocal, $\frac43$.  See my proof.  Then I just did manipulations to arrive at the $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, which was what we wanted to show.

Comment: ok, i see what you did

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with what you have done. For every $\epsilon>0$, you needed to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $0<|x-1|<\delta \implies |\frac{2+4x}{3}-2|<\epsilon$. Your first derivations (before you say "This is where I need help") actually find such a $\delta$ (as they are all "if and only if" statements). That is, you have shown $\delta = \frac{3}{4}\epsilon$ works. I suggest you take some time for your proof to "sink in" so as to clear any confusion that you may have.

Comment: You stated the first part of my solution is correct. What I am confused on though is how my second part is correct. How can I pick a constant such as $\frac43$ for the purpose of canceling out the $\frac34$ for the ϵ? Or I guess, what does that mean when I do that? I am just following an example from a book without understanding it, but I do not know how to understand it.