# verify $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(4x^2+2x+5)=5$

Tags: calculus, limits

Verify:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(4x^2+2x+5)=5$$
On a simple linear function it's easy to use the limit definition "$|f(x)-L|$ becomes arbitrarily small" but it won't work in this situation. But I'm supposed to use that definition somehow. The function won't factor. I'm not sure what to do.

We haven't learned limit laws yet so my professor wouldn't accept that.

EDIT: Changed my limit definition. Got it mixed up.

Comment: Wait, what's to stop you from just plugging the zero in? The limit isn't of indeterminate form...

Comment: That wouldn't be a "proof"

Comment: @Zack: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: We haven't gotten to delta-epsilon proofs yet

Comment: @Zack If you haven't gotten to $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs yet, how do you define limits? You can't possibly expect to prove a statement involving limits if you haven't precisely defined what a limit is! If you give us your definition of a limit, that would make answering your question easier for us to write and more understandable for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min\{1, \epsilon/6\} > 0$. Then observe that if $0 < |x - 0| < \delta$, then:
\begin{align*}
|(4x^2 + 2x + 5) - (5)|
&= |4x^2 + 2x| \\
&= |x(4x + 2)| \\
&= |x||4x + 2| \\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{6}|4x + 2| &\text{since } |x - 0| < \delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{6} \\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{6}(|4x| + |2|) &\text{by the triangle inequality} \\
&= \frac{\epsilon}{6}(4|x| + 2) \\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{6}(4(1) + 2) &\text{since } |x - 0| < \delta \leq 1 \\
&= \frac{\epsilon}{6}(6) \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: ok I think $|x||4x+2|$ is the answer my professor is looking for

Answer (score 3):

I think a slightly simpler choice than the other answers is $\delta = \min\{\sqrt{\epsilon/8}, \epsilon/4\}$. Then if $|x - 0| = |x| < \delta$,

$$
|(4x^2 + 2x + 5) - 5| = |4x^2 + 2x| \le |4x^2| + |2x| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.
$$

Comment: Should that be $\sqrt{\epsilon / 8}$ instead of $\sqrt\epsilon / 8$?

Comment: @Théophile Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you shown in class that polynomials are continuous everywhere? If not, see [this post](http://mathrefresher.blogspot.com/2009/02/polynomials-are-continuous.html) for a sketch of a proof by induction on the polynomial degree of this extremely useful fact.

Next, if a function $f$ is continuous at $c$, then 
$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c).$$
This is exactly the definition of continuity. So you can just plug in the 0 into your polynomial.

Comment: Actually that is in the next section of our book, on limit laws. We are not supposed to use those. But I see that that is an acceptable answer otherwise

Comment: Adriano has posted a direct proof above. One lesson to take away from this exercise is that proving general theorems, while sometimes more work up front, will then save you a lot of trouble later when you need to compute special cases!