# $\delta$ = min {1, $\epsilon$} works for proving $\lim_{x->0}$ $x^3$ = 0?

Tags: analysis, epsilon-delta

I'm quite sure that $\delta$=$\epsilon^{1/3}$ works well,

but I'm not sure $\delta$  = min {1, $\epsilon$} works as well.

If $\delta$  = min {1, $\epsilon$}, then in the case of $\epsilon$ < 1

|$x^3$| = $x^2$|x| < |x| < $\epsilon$.

And similarly for the case of $\epsilon$ ≥ 1 where $\delta$ = 1.

Does this argument work?

Comment: Note that if δ works then every δ'<=δ works, and that min{1,ϵ}<=ϵ^{1/3} for every ϵ.

Comment: Thanks! The criteria seems useful to me!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: @Rustyn ?? How do you understand "f(ϵ)<g(ϵ) for every ϵ"?

Comment: Nevermind Did, ok? I'll delete whatever I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct. There are many possibilities for $\delta$, in fact, if $\delta$ is a number that works, then any number smaller than $\delta$ will also work. This follows directly from the definition of the limit, i.e. $|x < c| < \gamma$ holds whenever, $\gamma \le \delta$.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!