# How can I prove this function is discontinuous or continuous similar to Drichlet function?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function

$$F(x)= \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{when }x \in \mathbb Q \\3x & \text{when }x \in\mathbb Q^c \end{cases}$$

Show that $F$ is continuous or not on $x=3$ with $\epsilon-\delta$.

I tried to deal with problems just like doing on Dirichlet functions. Mistakenly or not, I couldn't. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I supposed epsilon is 1/2. And tried to find contradiction. And no conclusion still.

Comment: What is your guess? Is $f$ continuous at $x = 3$?

Comment: I guess it is not continuous at x=3. And with (limit of f at x=3)=L and epsilon=1/2 , i tried to find contradiction.

Comment: However, if you plug in $x=3$ into both $3x$ and $x^2$, they are both $9$. It is an indication that the function $f$ is continuous there.

Comment: Both x^2 and 3x are continuous at 3, and both assume the same value 9. So F is clearly continuous at 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ , be a positive number

To find a $\delta$ such that $|x-3|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(3)|<\epsilon$.

Case-I if $x\in \mathbb Q$

Then $|f(x)-f(3)|=|x^2-9|=|(x-3)(x+3)|$

Therefore we choose our $\delta$ to be $<1$, then $|x-3|<1$ implies $-1<x-3<1$ , adding 6 on both sides we get  $
x+3<7$.

$|f(x)-f(3)|=|x^2-9|=|(x-3)(x+3)|<|x-3|\cdot 7$

Therefore we can choose, $\delta $ to be $\dfrac{\epsilon}{7}$ for the case-I

Case-II , $ x $ is irrational number,

$|f(x)-f(3)|=|3x-9|=|3(x-3)|$

Therefore we can choose, $\delta $ to be $\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$ for the case-II

So, for all real $x$ we can choose $$\delta= min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{7}, \frac{\epsilon}{3} \}$$ which ends the proof of $f$ being continuous at 3.

Note: 1) For a better and clear understanding of  manipulation of $\delta $
 you can refer to this beautifully written answer which got 27 upvotes-[How to show that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1)

Comment: Oh! Thank you So much for detailed solution and informing another good things. I appreciate it.

Comment: One more observation, $\delta= min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{7}, \frac{\epsilon}{3} \}$  is same as $\delta= min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{7} \}$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Note that $x^{2} \geq 3x$ for all $x \geq 3$ and that $x^{2} \leq 3x$ for all $0 \leq x \leq 3$;
now
$
|F(3+h) - F(3)| \leq (3+h)^{2} - 9 = 6h+h^{2} \to 0
$
as $h \to 0+$
and
$
|F(3+h) - F(3)| \leq |(3+h)^{2} - 9| = |6h+h^{2}| \to 0
$
as $h \to 0-$,
so $|F(3+h) - F(3)| \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

let $\epsilon>0$,let $\delta = min(\frac{\epsilon}{7},1)$.
let $x$ satisfy $|x-3|<\delta$, if $x \in Q $, then we have:

$|F(x) - F(3)| = |x^2-9| = |x-3||x+3| \leq 7|x-3| < 7\delta \leq \epsilon$

if $x$ not in $Q$ we have:

$|F(x) - F(3)| = |3x-9| = 3|x-3| < 3\delta \leq 3 \frac{\epsilon}{7} < \epsilon$

so, for all x that satisfy $|x-3|<\delta$ we have $|F(x) - F(3)|<\epsilon$,
from here we see that $F(x)$ is continuous on x=3.