# Let $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

a) Prove that $g$ is continuous at $0$
This is fairly straight forward $ \forall \epsilon >0$  $\exists \delta >0$ s.t. when $|x-c|<\delta$, it follows that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$

At $c=0$, $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$

$\sqrt[3]{x} < \epsilon$

$x < \epsilon^3$

Letting $\delta = \epsilon^3$

$|x-c|<\delta \rightarrow |x-c|<\epsilon^3$, $c=0$

$\sqrt[3]{x-0}<\epsilon$

$|f(x)-c|<\epsilon$

b) Prove that g is continuous at a point $c \neq 0$
I am having a bit more trouble with this one but somehow I'm supposed to use $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$
Would I let $a=\sqrt[3]{x} $ and $b=\sqrt[3]{c}$?
Do I have to use this or is there a different way? Exactly how do I use that identity?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be $(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: @NicholasStull thanks for catching that, I fixed it.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Comment: I believe that you would use the substitutions you propose. Note that the quadratic polynomial has no zeroes, so that factor always has one sign.

Comment: One  thing that might help: If $a>0$, $b>0$, $\min\{a^2,b^2\} < a^2+b^2+ab \leq 3\max\{a^2,b^2\}$. A similar statement holds if $a<0,b<0$.

Comment: @NicholasStull, what I have now is that  as $f(c)$ varies by $\epsilon$, i.e. $\sqrt[3]{c} + \epsilon, \sqrt[3]{c} - \epsilon$ , we have $x$ that varies by $(\sqrt[3]{c} - \epsilon)^3, (\sqrt[3]{c}+\epsilon)^3$ and I want the min of those as my $\delta$? Or am I missing something here?